# Python Panda drop() function not working after dictionary conversion; using Yfinance API

Tags: python, pandas, yfinance

Using the yfinance API I pulled data from there option chain object and converted it to a dictionary. I tried to delete all rows that contained "True" in the column labeled "inTheMoney" however when I run the program it does not do so.

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

price  = 100
ticker = yf.Ticker("SPY")
opt = ticker.option_chain('2022-11-18')
df = pd.DataFrame(opt.puts)
#df = df.drop(df[(df['inTheMoney'] != 'True')].index)
df = df.drop(['contractSymbol', 'lastTradeDate', 'change', 'percentChange', 'volume', 'openInterest', 'impliedVolatility', 'contractSize', 'currency'], axis = 1)
print(df)
```

I also tried to use a for loop and loc but that did not work either.

```
for index in range(len(df)):
    #print(df.loc[index, 'strike'])
    if df.loc[index, 'strike'] < 100:
        print(df.loc[index])
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just:

```
df = df.drop(df[(df['inTheMoney'] != True)].index) #do not use quotes
```

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate it. Can't believe I missed that.